# FreeMarker interpolation results used inline with a second interpolation

Tags: freemarker

Let me start with I'm not a programmer by trade, but I'm learning the best I can. I'm trying to build a template to take the result of one FreeMarker interpolation result and use that as a variable for another. I hope I'm using the terms correctly.

For example, I want the result of (entity.customer.organization.name) to be used in:

${blurb["organizationXXXAttire"]!}

Where **XXX** is the result of (entity.customer.organization.name)

If it was just a blurb with out a variable company name it would look like:

${blurb["organizationCompanyAttire"]!}

I thought the following would work but it did not:

<#assign organization = (entity.customer.organization.name)>

${blurb["organization<@organization?interpret>Attire"]!}

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply `${blurb["organization${entity.customer.organization.name}Attire"]!}`.

`?interpret` is only needed if you have a string that contains a piece of template. Besides you can't call directives (`<@...>`, `<#...>`) inside an expression.